# Recognise click over current location marker in Android Google Maps

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

In Google Maps V2 for Android, what would be the best option to recognise when the user has clicked the current location marker (blue one with white border)?

I don't get any example in the Internet and the only way I can imagine is this:

```
googleMap.setOnMapClickListener(new OnMapLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onMapClick(LatLng point) {
                // currentLocation is the location set by onLocationChanged method
                if (currentLocation != null
                            && (currentLocation.getLatitude() == point.latitude
                            && currentLocation.getLongitude() == point.longitude)) {
                        toastIt("Click over current position!");
                    }
            }
        });
```

Comment: check this similar [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16496715/3419997)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know it is late but for any one searching for this 
It is supported now natively (Since 18 Sept 2017)

from the page mentioned below :

Use the new GoogleMap.OnMyLocationClickListener to detect when the user clicks the My Location blue dot. (Issue 35822305)

```
@Override
public void onMyLocationClick(@NonNull Location location) {
  Toast.makeText(this, "Current location:\n" + location, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

I suggest to follow this page for the latest updates 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/releases

Answer (score 2):

You can add user location marker and take the reference of it's id:

```
mUserMarkerId = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng)
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                        .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE)))
                        .getId();
```

And with the `onMarkerClickListener` you can detect if the marker clicked was the user marker

```
mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new OnMarkerClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
            if (marker.getId().equalsIgnoreCase(mUserMarkerId))
                // Clicked user marker
            }

            return true;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

It's better solution

```
map.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng)
            {
                Location location=getLocation();
                if(map.isMyLocationEnabled()&&location!=null)
                {
                    float distance[]=new float[1];
                    Location.distanceBetween(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), latLng.latitude, latLng.longitude, distance);
                    if(distance[0]<location.getAccuracy())
                    {
                        Log.d(TAG, "onMapClick: It is user!");
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```